# Ktor Websocket feature with ContentNeogation feature (JSON / GSON) in ktor

Tags: json, serialization, websocket, gson, ktor

I'm trying to de/serialize JSON Payload for a Websocket in ktor.

Currently I'm doing something like

```
// Global property
lateinit var globalGson: Gson

// fun Application.module()
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    gson {
        setDateFormat(DateFormat.LONG)
        setPrettyPrinting()
        globalGson = create() // init global property
    }
}
```

and when handling websockets:

```
session.incoming.consumeEach { frame ->
            if (frame is Frame.Text)
              globalGson.fromJson(frame.readText(), MyClass::class.java) // use global property
}
```

Is there a recommanded way using the Websocket feature with GSON feature?

Is there any elegant way to access the registered ContentNeogation for a specific type and use it without an ApplicationPipeline? (I belive WebSocketSession doesnt have that)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to use the `ContentNegotiation` feature with `Websockets` to serialize/deserialize data of frames. The best you can do is to directly use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library or any other library of such kind.

Update: Since 2.0.0, Ktor has the support of [WebSockets serialization](https://ktor.io/docs/websocket-serialization.html).

Comment: Why is this the case?